# insert a line the bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

I would like to insert a line in the bottom of a div.

My html file :

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div style="float:left;width:350px;height:360px;position:relative">
    <img style="position:absolute;left:0;" class="circular c_imgs" src="Edit.jpg"/>
    <img style="position:absolute;left:0;margin-top:175px" class="circular c_imgs" src="lessons.jpg"/>

        <img style="position:absolute;right:0;" class="circular c_imgs" src="makeup.jpg"/>
    <img style="position:absolute;right:0;margin-top:175px" class="circular c_imgs" src="fun.JPG"/>
    </div>


    <hr color="#337AB7" size="10" width="%100" style="position:absolute;bottom:0" >
</div>
```

what is my wrong ?

[image]

---

**updated**

my css :

```
.bottomdiv:after{
content:'';
width:100%;
height:10px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
background:#337AB7;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

my html file :

```
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
<div class="bottomdiv" style="position:relative">
    <div style="float:left;width:350px;height:360px;position:relative">
    <img style="position:absolute;left:0;" class="circular c_imgs" src="../../../20100202-Cooking-090-Edit.jpg"/>
    <img style="position:absolute;left:0;margin-top:175px" class="circular c_imgs" src="../../../lessons.jpg"/>

        <img style="position:absolute;right:0;" class="circular c_imgs" src="../../../makeup.jpg"/>
    <img style="position:absolute;right:0;margin-top:175px" class="circular c_imgs" src="../../../fun.JPG"/>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

But...
[image]

Comment: Your nested div has `float:left`, which will put it on the left of your line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `100%` instead of `%100`:

```html
    <hr color="#337AB7" size="10" width="100%" style="position:absolute;bottom:0" >
```

Another easy way to do it is with CSS `:after`:

```css
    div:after{
    content:'';
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#337AB7;
    border-radius:5px;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @S.M_Emamian i updated my answer, the bar will now be be on the left where it is supposed to be. Th reason it isn't working as you want is that .bottomdiv doesn't have a height, so it appears at the top

Comment: give bottomdiv a height to fix the problem

Comment: Let's be clear, `hr` is _not_ a deprecated tag, and there's no reason to avoid using it.  It's in the [w3c documentation for HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/hr.html), and was even given semantic purpose as a part of that.

Comment: @JoshBurgess My bad, I thought it was depreciated as i read that it was. I should have looked that up.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try wrapping all of your images inside a div `.inner` - then apply a border to the bottom of that... With a little tweaking you can position your images relative in a grid and add a `clearfix` so the `inner` will clear them and the line will come out of the bottom of the modal.

```css
body {
  background: #999
}
.modal {
  padding: 30px;
  max-width: 680px;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px; 
}
.inner {
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
img{
  width: 46%;
  margin: 2%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: aliceblue;
}
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="inner clearfix">
    <img class="circular c_imgs" src="Edit.jpg"/>
    <img class="circular c_imgs" src="lessons.jpg"/>
    <img class="circular c_imgs" src="makeup.jpg"/>
    <img class="circular c_imgs" src="fun.JPG"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Pen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqRvVZ)